# Kotlin + Spring 5 functional beans mixed with traditional beans test WITHOUT spring-boot

Tags: spring, kotlin, dsl, springrunner

Suppose I have a class injected many spring beans :

```
@Component
open class CoreContext {

  @Inject
  protected lateinit var bean1 : SomeInterface1

  @Inject
  protected lateinit var bean2 : SomeInterface2

}
```

It is defined in the `context:component-scan` block in `core.xml`  , and in traditional SpringTest , it works well like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ["classpath:core.xml"])
class CoreContextTest { ... }
```

Now , I want to try to use DSL-style to define beans , and use these DSL-defined beans with old beans :

```
@Component
class MyBeans : CoreContext() {

  val beans = beans {

    bean("simpleComparator") {
      Comparator<Number> { o1, o2 -> o1.toInt().minus(o2.toInt()) }
    }

  }
}
```

`MyBeans` is located in the `component-scan` packages , and IntelliJ correctly detects it.
[image: detected by IntelliJ]

But how to test this simpleComparator ?

I try to `@Inject simpleComparator : Comparator<Number>` , but intelliJ complains `No beans of Comparator<Number> type found` . And at runtime , it failed as expected.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = ["classpath:core.xml"])
class MyBeansTest {


  @Inject
  private lateinit var context: ApplicationContext

//  @Inject // No beans of Comparator<Number> type found
//  private lateinit var simpleComparator : Comparator<Number> 

  @Test
  fun printBeans() {
    logger.info("context = {}", context)
    context.beanDefinitionNames.forEach { name ->
      logger.info("{}", name)
    }
  }

}
```

And when I want to print out all registered beans , I cannot find the `simpleComparator` bean .

It seems all related info are SpringBoot-based . But I cannot find a pure `SpringRunner` unit test example. Thanks.

versions :

```
<kotlin.version>1.3.30</kotlin.version>
<spring.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

Comment: `@Component` should be an `@Configuration` and make sure that your component-scan actually covers the package that the `MyBeans` class is in.

Comment: Yes . `MyBeans` is located in the `component-scan` packages , and IntelliJ correctly detects it. (I've updated the question , append an image).

Comment: The beans need to be in a file named `Beans.kt`. See https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/functional

Comment: I read @sdeleuze 's git , I tried but It doesn't work. 

I design `class MyBeans : CoreContext() ` because I want to inject old beans into the DSL-style bean. @sdeleuze's sample code doesn't extend (reuse / mix) any old-style beans.

Comment: Why would you need to extend `CoreContext` for that? You can just inject the beans or get them in the functional config as well, using `ref("bean-name")` or `ref<Type>()`... The `beans` need to be toplevel afaik.

Comment: Even I define a top level `val beans = bean { ... }` , with this`simpleComparator` . `MyBeansTest` still cannot `see` it... Is there any document about this ? I cannot find one. It seems @sdeleuze 's beans are loaded by `beans.initialize(this)`  https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-kotlin-functional/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/functional/Application.kt#L25 , but how about Unit test ? mmm...